# Not receiving response after PostAsync

Tags: c#, post, asynchronous, async-await, asp.net-web-api2

I have next part of code :

```
using (var client = new HttpClient()) // from Windows.Web.Http;
{
    //setup client
    var tokenUri = new Uri(apiBaseUri + "/token");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                        new HttpMediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    //setup login data
    IHttpContent formContent = new HttpFormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
    {
         new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
         new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", userName),
         new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password),
    });

    //send request
    HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.PostAsync(tokenUri, formContent);

    //get access token from response body
    var responseJson = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var jObject = JObject.Parse(responseJson);
    return jObject.GetValue("access_token").ToString();
}
```

This makes call to my Web Api. I have checked if it's really works with fiddler - as result I can see response what i espect (Bearer token). But in code this response are never received.

What is the problem?

Comment: What do you mean, responseMessage is null?

Comment: @AndyWiesendanger, nothing... Maybe i should set some timeout to be sure, but i wait a lot of time and nothing happens

Comment: How are you calling this method? Are you blocking it with `Task.Result`?

Comment: I'm talking about the method that calls this method

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov  than yes `var token = GetAPIToken(UserName, Password, ApiBaseUri).Result;` something like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
var token = GetAPIToken(UserName, Password, ApiBaseUri).Result;
```

Causes a classic deadlock. [You shouldn't be blocking on async code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) with `Task.Result` or `Task.Wait`. Instead, you need to go "async all the way" and await on it too, making the method higher up the call stack `async Task as well`:

```
public async Task GetApiTokenAsync()
{
    var token = await GetAPIToken(UserName, Password, ApiBaseUri);
}
```